# TranspileError occurs when using Simulator Stabilizer

Tags: qiskit, qiskit-runtime

I am writing a small quantum program for supporting polynomial arithmetic, implemented from [Space-efficient quantum multiplication of polynomials for binary finite fields with sub-quadratic Toffoli gate count](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1910.02849.pdf) and [Concrete quantum cryptanalysis of binary elliptic curves](https://tches.iacr.org/index.php/TCHES/article/view/8741). To run the code, I am using the `simulator_stabilizer` backend provided by IBM.

```
service = QiskitRuntimeService()
qc = QuantumCircuit()
backend = service.backend("simulator_stabilizer")
```

However, when I run it, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):                                                                                                                    
  File "/home/adarsh/NITK/MP/Project/qbpolynomial.py", line 333, in <module>                                                                          
    print(qpoly3)                                                                                                                                     
  File "/home/adarsh/NITK/MP/Project/qbpolynomial.py", line 300, in __str__                                                                           
    coeffs = self.measure()                                                                                                                           
  File "/home/adarsh/NITK/MP/Project/qbpolynomial.py", line 221, in measure                                                                           
    return list(job.result().get_counts().keys())[0][::-1]                                                                                            
  File "/home/adarsh/NITK/MP/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/qiskit_ibm_runtime/runtime_job.py", line 222, in result                                
    raise RuntimeJobFailureError(f"Unable to retrieve job result. {error_message}")                                                                   
qiskit_ibm_runtime.exceptions.RuntimeJobFailureError: 'Unable to retrieve job result. TranspilerError: "Unable to translate the operations in the circ
uit: [\'ccx\', \'measure\', \'x\', \'cx\', \'swap\'] to the backend\'s (or manually specified) target basis: [\'y\', \'sx\', \'if_else\', \'delay\', \
'swap\', \'save_amplitudes_sq\', \'while_loop\', \'snapshot\', \'z\', \'save_state\', \'continue_loop\', \'save_expval\', \'barrier\', \'cx\', \'for_l
oop\', \'save_probabilities_dict\', \'break_loop\', \'s\', \'sxdg\', \'cz\', \'sdg\', \'save_expval_var\', \'reset\', \'id\', \'save_clifford\', \'roe
rror\', \'quantum_channel\', \'measure\', \'h\', \'save_stabilizer\', \'cy\', \'save_probabilities\', \'qerror_loc\', \'x\', \'pauli\', \'set_stabiliz
er\']. This likely means the target basis is not universal or there are additional equivalence rules needed in the EquivalenceLibrary being used. For 
more details on this error see: https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.transpiler.passes.BasisTranslator.html#translation_errors'
```

This program works without issues when using the `AerSimulator` of Qiskit. Can anyone point out what is my mistake or guide me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

In seems like a problem related with the supported instruction set on [that specific backend](https://quantum.ibm.com/services/resources?tab=simulators&search=stabilizer&system=simulator_stabilizer). Probably a bug, because the list should cover your circuit instructions.

A possible workaround is to transpile it on client-side before submitting:

```python
from qiskit import transpile
transpiled_qc = transpile(qc, basis_gates=backend.configuration().basis_gates)
```

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately, the error is still coming, this time from the local `transpile` function. The circuit is dynamically constructed, could that be a possible reason?

Comment: same error? it could be indeed from a the dynamic part. Very hard to debug without the circuit. Probably at this point you should submit and issue https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit/issues/new

Comment: Alright, I will do that. Meanwhile, I have switched to a different backend for now where it works fine. Thanks